# Behavior is changing after Inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

I have one following ApplContext class.
http://codetidy.com/4498/ (This is 400 lines file.No need to read this file completely.)

Following class is extending above class.

```
public class validatorApplContext extends ApplContext {

    private static final String FAKE_FILE_NAME = "file://";
    private static final String USER_MEDIUM_ALL = "all";
    private static final String CSS_VERSION_3 = "css3";
    private static final String PROFILE_NONE = "none";
    private static final int DEFAULT_WARNING_LEVEL = 0;

    public validatorApplContext(String lang) {
        super(lang);
    }
}
```

Now I have another class which returns the ApplContext object.

```
public class ApplContextFactory {

    private static final String FAKE_FILE_NAME = "file://";
    private static final String USER_MEDIUM_ALL = "all";
    private static final String CSS_VERSION_3 = "css3";
    private static final String PROFILE_NONE = "none";
    private static final int DEFAULT_WARNING_LEVEL = 0;

    public static ApplContext getApplContext(String lang) {
        ApplContext ac = new ApplContext(lang);
        ac.setWarningLevel(DEFAULT_WARNING_LEVEL);
        ac.setCssVersion(CSS_VERSION_3);
        ac.setProfile(PROFILE_NONE);
        ac.setMedium(USER_MEDIUM_ALL);
        ac.setFakeURL(FAKE_FILE_NAME);
        ac.setTreatVendorExtensionsAsWarnings(true);
        return ac;
    }
}
```

Now in the ApplContextFactory class when I am doing

```
ApplContext ac = new ApplContext(lang);
```

every thing on client side is working perfectly fine.
But when I am doing

```
ApplContext ac = new validatorApplContext(lang);
```

it is not working.
Looks like inheritance is causing some issue.

Please help if you are able to identify the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Unless you have left out important parts of your code, I don't see how it can compile.

Comment: Please specify the class.Is it validatorApplContext or ApplContext or FactoryClass or Client Code(Not pasted here)

Comment: What do you mean by "It is not working."? Getting any error OR program is not giving expected output? If so, what is your expected output?

Comment: Not giving expected output

Comment: @shantanu - Add relevant parts of your ApplContext class, particularly the constructors.

Comment: @Perception. I guest constructor is there. Please see the line number 81 in the given link.

Comment: It's weird how you define those static fields and then override them in the getApplContext. Also you don't seem to use the ApplContextFactory, why did you add that class in the initial question?

Comment: I'm not digging through an externally linked file, sorry. When posting questions on SO its your responsibility to include a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @Bogdan. getApplContext is getting used in client code. ac = ApplContextFactory.getApplContext(locale.getDisplayLanguage()); I did not pasted that here.

Comment: @Perception. Agree with you and sorry for not following that completely. As this is very weird issue so I thought giving the complete file might help. Again sorry for giving such a large file

Comment: @shantanu - Your factory class has six extra lines of codes, setting additional information on the newly constructed `ApplContext` instance. Are you replicating that logic in the `ApplContext(string)` constructor? If not, theres your issue. Would be much easier to answer this question if you actually included the relevant code like we are asking.

Comment: @Perception.>> Your factory class has six extra lines of codes. How will this matter. Same constructor is getting executed for both cases. Any way I will try to include the AppCOntext class with constructor code.

Comment: @shantanu But the setters you are calling on it change the values and you return that `ApplContext` with those changed values. That returned `ApplContext` will be different than simply a `new validatorApplContext(lang)`.

Comment: @ryan. Please note that new ApplContext(lang); and new validatorApplContext(lang) is getting as used at same place. Those setters will be executed for both the cases.

Comment: You say you are not getting the expected results. What are the expected results? What is the difference that is not expected?

Comment: @Ryan. That I can't explain/paste here as this is a part of big web application.

Comment: Please post the relevant part of ApplContext class. Do you have those private static final variables there to? What are those setters (setWarningLevel) doing? How do you get the values of the warning level in the client (do you use getters or you refer directly the static variables)?

Answer (score 2):

In Java, when you have a class with an attribute, you **can't override** it while inheriting, like you can with methods. Attributes just work differently.

You can add another attribute with the same name, and this is what you did. So your ApplContextFactory has two fields named FAKE_FILE_NAME, one defined in ApplContextFactory, and one in validatorApplContext. Which one is read **does not depend on the instance type**, like it does with methods. It depends solely on the type of the reference. So:

```
// an object with two FAKE_FILE_NAME attributes
validatorApplContext vac = new validatorApplContext ();
ApplContext AC= ac; // the same object, just a different variable

System.out.println(v.FAKE_FILE_NAME) //  this reads from validatorApplContext
ac.FAKE_FILE_NAME = "test"; // this sets in ac, because this is the type of the variable
System.out.println(v.FAKE_FILE_NAME) //  no change visible here
System.out.println(ac.FAKE_FILE_NAME) //  change visible here.
```

You might say that access to methods is dynamic (uses information available at run-time) and access to attributes is static (only uses types available during compilation). If you want to use polymorphism, you need to use methods.

In your case, all the code in ApplContext sees the original values of FAKE_FILE_NAME and all the code inside validatorApplContext sees the values set in the constructor.

The simplest solution would be to add getters and setters to both classes (NOT static!), that would get and set all the static fields. The getters will override each other. But you will still have two copies of the attributes, which seems not what you really want to do.

Frankly, the code looks a bit wrong. As if you had a large experience with some scripting language and tried to build your first larger project in Java, following practices that don't really fit and are going against the grain of the language. If this is so, expect much more problems.

Comment: @fderger, Thanks for explanation. But I am not trying to override  FAKE_FILE_NAME variable. validatorApplContext and ApplContextFactory don't have inheritance relationship.

Answer (score 0):

If your client does something like this:

`ApplContext ac = ApplContextFactory.getInstance(language);
logger.log(ac.DEFAULT_WARNING_LEVEL, message);`

This will get the value of DEFAULT_WARNING_LEVEL defined in ApplContext even if ac has the type ValidatorApplContext at runtime. The binding of static references is determined at compile time and ac has ApplContext as the declared type.